# Mapping An Enum in Code First

Tags: c#, enums, ef-code-first

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enums with EF code-first - standard method to seeding DB and then using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344032/enums-with-ef-code-first-standard-method-to-seeding-db-and-then-using)

Is there a simple way to map an enum using code first EF.

Here is my poco class.. where FooStatus is an enumeration. The column is not getting created when the database is initialized.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CreatorId { get; set; }

    public Creator Creator { get; set; }

    public FooStatus Status { get; set; }

    public int Applications { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344032/enums-with-ef-code-first-standard-method-to-seeding-db-and-then-using