# Mapping DB values to Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I created a new `Enum` class from db table `Role` which has `RoleId` and `RoleType`.

```
public enum UserType
{
    Student = 1,
    Teacher = 4
    Admin = 5 
}
```

Here 1,4,5 are RoleId(Primary Key) from db. What i did is i looked manually for the db primary key value for each role and mapped that to `enum`.

The demerit here is every time i need to update the `enum` class when db `RoleId` Changes.

Is there any other standard practice to map db values as `enum` collections?

Any suggestions will help

Comment: Just cast the value. `(UserType)some_value;`

Comment: what do you meant? `(UserType)some_value`. I am asking for mapping db values to `enum`. How does it helps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/dynamic-enum-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you're using EF and code-first, you should be able to just use the Enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344032/enums-with-ef-code-first-standard-method-to-seeding-db-and-then-using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, I've been facing same problem.
One of the possible solutions is using T4 template (codegeneration).
You can implement some custom logic to select table(s) and description/value columns.
Something like this

```
    //Start write enum file:        
    #>
    namespace <#=enumNameSpace#>
    {
        public enum <#=enumName#>Enum
        {
        <#
          command.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}",TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE);
          var columnReader = command.ExecuteReader();
          while (columnReader.Read())
          {#>   
               <#=columnReader[DESCRIPTION_COLUMN_NAME].ToString()#> = <#=columnReader[VALUE_COLUMN_NAME].ToString()#>,
          <#    
          }#>
        }
    }
    <#
```

You can read more in this great [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417283/Creating-Enums-from-Database-Lookup-Tables)