# How to map enum property on codefirst structure?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

How to map enums property in codefirst mapping?

**My enum:**

```
public enum GenderType : int
{
    Male = 0,
    Female = 1
}
```

**My Model**

```
public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
    public int gender { get; set; }
    public GenderType Gender
    {
```

// NOT WORKING : Can not implicity convert type int .... 
            get { return gender; }
            set { gender = (int)value; }
        }

**My Configuration**

```
            Property(model => model.Comment)
                .HasMaxLength(4000)
                .IsUnicode();

            Property(model => model.Culture)
                .IsOptional()
                .HasMaxLength(10);

----- HOW TO WRITE GENDER?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerations are supported by EF from version 5 (EF Code First 5) going forward so if you are using that it should work automatically, on the other hand if you are using an older version then you can use the solution mentioned **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6344096/439667)** as a workaround (i used it and it works). The main idea of the solution is that older versions of EF ignore them without any errors so you need to use another property of type `int` and map that property then the property of the type of enumeration can simply become a wrapper around that property.