# enums in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework-4, enums, code-first

please,  how to work with enums in Entity Framework code first. i want that in my class "Annonce" i can have this proprety

```
public Status EtatAnnonce { get; set; }
```

and Status is defined like this

```
public enum Status
{
    Pending,
    Approved
}
```

Comment: Check this,
http://the--semicolon.blogspot.com/p/handling-enum-in-code-first-entity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a converter field to store the value as int in the database.

```
public int MyEnumValueInt {get;set;}

[NotMapped]
public MyEnum MyEnumValue
{
    get{ return (MyEnum)MyEnumValueInt;
    set{ MyEnumValueInt = (int)value;
}
```

Note: The enum support will be improved in EF 5.

Answer (score 1):

Will point you towards

[EF5 does not create enum columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647874/ef5-does-not-create-enum-columns)

To give a summary of enum support in Entity Framework code first:

EF4: Not supported

EF5: only supported if you are targeting .net framework 4.5 and higher

EF6: only supported if you target .net 4.0 and higher

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've answered two questions regarding Enums in EF; these should help you along:

[Enums with EF code-first - standard method to seeding DB and then using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344032/enums-with-ef-code-first-standard-method-to-seeding-db-and-then-using/6344096#6344096)

and

[EF 4.1 Code First - map enum wrapper as complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667473/ef-4-1-code-first-map-enum-wrapper-as-complex-type/5673768#5673768)

Answer (score 0):

You can use private properties in your model to map your data to whatever property type you want.

```
// Model
public class Piece
{

    // Subclass Piece to add mappings for private properties
    public class PieceConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Piece>
    {
        public PieceConfig()
        {
            Property(b => b.dbtype); // needed for EF to see the private property
        }
    }

    [Column("type", TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    private string dbtype { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public PIECE type
    {
        get { return (PIECE)Enum.Parse(typeof(PIECE), dbtype); }
        set { dbtype= value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add the configuration to your OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Piece.PieceConfig());
```