# EF5 does not generate enumeration field with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I'm working with Entity Framework 5 code first in combination with MySQL 5. In one of my models, I'm using an enumeration:

```
public class CoolModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Coolnesses Coolness;
}

public enum Coolnesses { SomewhatCool, KindaCool, Cool, VeryCool }

public class EFEnumTestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CoolModel> CoolStuff { get; set; }

    public EFEnumTestContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

But when using this model, something weird happens. I simply try and add some items to the database, then retrieve them:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new EFEnumTestContext())
        {
            context.CoolStuff.Add(new CoolModel() { Coolness = Coolnesses.Cool });
            context.CoolStuff.Add(new CoolModel() { Coolness = Coolnesses.SomewhatCool });
            context.CoolStuff.Add(new CoolModel() { Coolness = Coolnesses.KindaCool });
            context.CoolStuff.Add(new CoolModel() { Coolness = Coolnesses.VeryCool });
            context.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var coolThing in context.CoolStuff)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(coolThing.Id.ToString() + ": " + coolThing.Coolness);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But on executing my program, I notice that my database does not contain the column for my enumeration. At first sight, my program does work, but only because during the first `Console.WriteLine()` it's still printing from what it's in memory.

After a couple of searches I found out [more people have run into this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647874/ef5-does-not-create-enum-columns), but all signs point towards it being a .NET4 vs .NET4.5 problem. I've just now created a console application from start with .NET4.5 as the target platform, added EF5 freshly to the project and the same behavior occurs. I'm starting to think it might be the MySQL provider for Entity Framework that doesn't support the generation of enums yet. Could this be it or am I forgetting something somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I tried to get it working with SQL Server just now, but the results are the same: No column in the table for the enumeration field. It's probably not the MySQL provider then, but what am I missing then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. As most always, it was something silly.

On my `CoolModel` I declared `Coolness` as a field, not as a property. Simply adding `{ get; set; }` to the line of code fixed it.

```
public class CoolModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Coolnesses Coolness { get; set; }
}
```